# Entity Framework 6 - Unable to update a single column in a table

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following method which is trying to update a single column (not the entire graph of the object!) in the database table (shipping cost):

```
    public void UpdateShippingCost(Entities.ShoppingCart shoppingCart)
    {
        // Map from domain entity to database object
        var shoppingCartRecord = Mapper.Map<ShoppingCart>(shoppingCart);

        shoppingCartRecord.ShippingCost = 99.99M;

        dbContext.ShoppingCart.Add(shoppingCartRecord);

        var entry = dbContext.Entry(shoppingCartRecord);
        entry.Property(e => e.ShippingCost).IsModified = true;
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

When the `entry.Property(e => e.ShippingCost).IsModified = true;`line is executed, I get the following error:

```
Additional information: SetModifiedProperty cannot be called because the object is not in a modified or unchanged state.
```

How can this be? I've certainly modified the object.

Comment: You're calling `Add()` just before you're requesting the entity entry. I guess the object is indeed in `Added` state. What's the point of marking one of the properties as `Modified` when the entire object is about to be persisted as `Added`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A call to `DBSet<>.Add()` will mark the entity as `Added`. So there's no sense in marking a specific property as `Modified`.

In order to update an existing entity, call `DbContext.Attach()` to EF start tracking the entity,  instead of `DbSet<>.Add()`.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I got careless and called .Add instead of .Attach.